# Dumping foreign servers and user mappings in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've been doing some testing in a scratch PostgreSQL database using foreign data wrappers.  I can dump foreign table definitions with pg_dump, but I'd like to dump the definitions for the wrappers and user mappings as well.  Is there any way to do this with vanilla pg_dump?

Comment: I'm not sure of exactly what you mean. Can you show DDL examples of what you created, and which parts are / are not dumped? (Maybe they're global objects and you need to use `pg_dumpall --globals-only` ?)

Comment: The DDL commands used were 'CREATE SERVER', 'CREATE USER MAPPING', and 'CREATE FOREIGN TABLE'.  For brevity, I'm not going to include them all here, but essentially I'm defining an external database server to query, setting up user/password for that server, and telling PostgreSQL how the external table is laid out in terms of column data types.

Comment: I should also note that `pg_dump -t foreign_table_name` dumps only the foreign table definition, but *not* the foreign server and mapping definitions, which are needed in order to query the foreign table.

Answer (score 3):

`pg_dump -s` did the trick well enough, although it dumped everything else in the schema as well.  I wanted something a little more fine grained so I wouldn't have to manually edit the SQL dump.